# How Can I import and compile my code with gtk.h in Mac OS Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, gtk

I have downloaded and installed Gtk2 with MacPorts:

```
sudo port install gtk2
```

And I have made sure that the system configuration with this too:

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0
```

But when it comes the time that I put down this line in Xcode:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

I still get the following error msg:

```
Gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing here? Any configuration in XCode or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell your project where gtk lives.

Best way to do this is to go into your project's "Build Settings" and look for the setting named "Header Search Paths".  Add a direct path to your Gtk's include directory there.  I suggest just a direct path like `/usr/local/lib/gtk` or whatever the true location of it is (and don't use fancy aliases or relative paths or things like this just yet, until you get really accustomed to them).

Then, make sure the framework (`.framework`, `.dylib`) or static library (a `.a` lib file) or whatever is included in your project so the linker knows which Gtk library to link against.

I also noticed a potentially useful [tutorial here](http://live.gnome.org/GTK%2B/OSX/Building).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added the root path of my GTK-2.0 into my "Header Search Paths". However, I don't really know how to "make sure the framework or static library or whatever is included in your project". I just use "Add Existing Files" but it's proven not effective. Could you explain more on this? Thanks.